# Виджет-выезжалка для андроид

Tags: android

Возник такой вопрос, есть ли возможность вывести на Android выезжающий блок сверху. Т.е.

1. Пользователь что-то делает на устройстве.
2. Плавно выезжает сверху полоска поверх основного контента
3. В полоске некий текст и некая кнопка
4. По нажатию на кнопку, панель плавно скрывается и начинает выполняться какое то действие

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Орфографию только немного подправьте и можете пользоваться Sliding Drawer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Comment: @ЕвгенийВасиленко, к вашему сведению Sliding Drawer Deprecated since API level 17, поэтому его использовать нерекомендуется. А автору посоветовал бы просто использовать любой контролл (даже LinearLayout)  и самому его анимировать в нужное время. (к примеру анимировать его margin)

Answer (score 1):

[ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) класс доступен с 3й версии андроида... для более ранних версий аналог [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) (c примерами кода)